# Iterative Binary Search in MIPS

Tags: mips, qtspim

I'm trying to create a iterative binary search in mips, below is my code. It works when searching for the middle value, otherwise it doesnt but i'm not sure why. I'm new to MIPs and trying to get better so any critique is appreciated

```
.data
myArray: .word 1 4 5 7 9 12 15 17 18 20 21 30
last: #the address that comes after the array
arraySize: .word 11

.globl main
.text

main:
  la $s0, myArray # array address
  lw $s1, arraySize # arraysize
  li $s2, 30 # address of last array entry
  jal Binsearch # perform binary search

  li $v0, 10
  syscall

Binsearch:
  li $t0,0                           #first = 0
  subu $t1, $s1, 1                   #last = array size -1

Loop: bge    $t0, $t1, DONE          # if ! (first < last)
  add $t2,$t0,$t1                    #first + last
  li $t3,2
  div $t2, $t3                       #$LO = middle index
  mflo $t3                           #$t3 = middle index
  li $s3,4                           #load the value 4 into s3
  multu $s3, $t3                     #multiply middle by 4 to get the offset
  mflo $t4                           #store the result in t4
  add $t4, $s0, $t4                  #t4 points to array[mid]
  lw $t5, ($t4)                      #load the value at array[mid] into t5
  beq $t5, $s2, return_mid           # if   t5 == s2  then return the index
  blt $t5, $s2, move_right           # if   t5 < s2 then move right
  subu $t1, $t3, 1                   #if this line is reached that means that none of the above
  j    Loop                          #conditions are true, so t5 > s2, last = mid -1
return_mid:
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $t3, $zero              # add the middle index to a0
    syscall                          #print the index
move_right:
  addi  $t0, $t3, 1                  # first = mid + 1
  j    Loop                          # jump to Loop
DONE:
  li $v0, 1
  li $a0, -1
  syscall

  j $ra #return to the caller
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, had to test for some corner cases and change the LOOP condition

```
.data
myArray: .word 1 4 5 7 9 12 15 17 18 20 21 30
last: #the address that comes after the array
arraySize: .word 11

.globl main
.text

main:
  la $s0, myArray # array address
  lw $s1, arraySize # arraysize
  li $s2, 20 #value youre searching for
  jal Binsearch # perform binary search

  li $v0, 10
  syscall

Binsearch:
  li $t0,0                           #first = 0
  move $t1, $s1                      #last = array size -1
  li $t6,1
  li $t7,4                           #checks for the last element in the array being the correct value
  multu $t7,$t1
  mflo  $t7
  add   $t7,$s0,$t7
  lw    $t5, ($t7)
  beq   $t5, $s2, last_num          # if  ==  then
  subu $t1, $s1, 1

Loop: bge $t0, $t1, DONE             # if ! (first < last)
  add $t2,$t0,$t1                    #first + last
  li $t3,2
  div $t2, $t3                       #$LO = middle index
  mflo $t3                           #$t3 = middle index
  beq $t2,$t6, special_case          #if first+last = 1 you want totake HI not LO
  li $t7,4                           #load the value 4 into t7
  multu $t7, $t3                     #multiply middle by 4 to get the offset
  mflo $t4                           #store the result in t4
  add $t4, $s0, $t4                  #t4 points to array[mid]
  lw $t5, ($t4)                      #load the value at array[mid] into t5
  beq $t5, $s2, return_mid           # if   t5 == s2  then return the index
  blt $t5, $s2, move_right           # if   t5 < s2 then move right
  subu $t1, $t3, 1                   #if this line is reached that means that none of the above
  j    Loop                          #conditions are true, so t5 > s2, last = mid -1
special_case:
    mfhi $t3                           #get the 1 value from hi
    li $t7,4                           #load the value 4 into t7
    multu $t7, $t3                     #multiply middle by 4 to get the offset
    mflo $t4                           #store the result in t4
    add $t4, $s0, $t4                  #t4 points to array[mid]
    lw $t5, ($t4)                      #load the value at array[mid] into t5
    beq $t5, $s2, return_mid           # if   t5 == s2  then return the index
return_mid:
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $t3, $zero              # add the middle index to a0
    syscall                          #print the index
    j $ra
move_right:
  addi  $t0, $t3, 1                  # first = mid + 1
  j    Loop                          # jump to Loop
last_num:
  li $v0, 1
  add $a0, $t1, $zero
  syscall
  j $ra
DONE:
  li $v0, 1
  li $a0, -1
  syscall

  j $ra #return to the caller
```